# How to get results using join ON LIKE operator in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-like

I am trying multiple joins in a single query to pull data from multiple tables.

Tables - `Places_main`, `User_interests`, `travel_list`

**`User_interests` table data:**

```
ID USERID INTERESTID
84  27       |18|   
85  27       |18|
```

**`Places_main` table data**

```
ID TAGS

1  |5|18|35|34|33
2  |5|18|35|33|34
```

**What I am trying to get here :**

Get list of places from Places_main table which is not in travel_list, and for "tags" column of places_main there is an entry in User_interests table in interestID column.

**This is query 1**

```
select * from places_main pm 
LEFT JOIN travel_list tl ON pm.ID = tl.PLACEID 
LEFT JOIN user_interests ui ON pm.TAGS NOT LIKE '%' || ui.interestid || '%'
where tl.ID is null and ui.ID is null
```

**This is same query 2 which is same as above but with hard-coded data**

```
select * from places_main pm 
LEFT JOIN travel_list tl ON pm.ID = tl.PLACEID 
LEFT JOIN user_interests ui ON pm.TAGS NOT LIKE '%18%'
where tl.ID is null and ui.ID is null
```

When I execute query with hardcoded value, it returns expected results, but when I run without hard-coded(1st query), it returns nothing.

How do I get get expected result without using hardcoded value.

Thanks for help in advance.

**Edit:**

If I remove pipe form table data and compare it as single value, it works fine. But with pipe in row it returns empty. Any suggestion for this.

Comment: Stop. See normalisation

Comment: If you are talking about places_main table for pipe separated values, I get it. But what I am trying to get is not possible??

Comment: You have sample data for two tables, but the query includes three tables...

Comment: All things are possible. Some are terrible.

Comment: @jarlh. Yeah, to understand this problem, you do not need third table info :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you shouldn't be storing tags like that. You should normalize your table to store one tag per row. Then all there is left to do will be a simple join:

```
create table user_interests (
    id int, 
    userid int,
    interestid int
    );

insert into user_interests values
(84 , 27       ,18),
(85 , 27       ,18);

create table places_main (
    id int,
    tag int
);

insert into places_main values
(1,5), (1,18), (1,35), (1,34), (1,33),
(2,5), (2,18), (2,35), (2,33), (2,34);

select * 
from places_main p
join user_interests u on p.tag = u.interestid;
```

#### [Demo normalized](http://rextester.com/WAG12023)

For your current design, here's an ugly solution:

```
create table places_main (
    id int,
    tags varchar(100)
);

insert into places_main values
(1,'|5|18|35|34|33'),
(2,'|5|18|35|33|34');

select * 
from places_main p
left join user_interests u
on concat('|', p.tags, '|') like concat('%|', u.interestid, '|%');
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/DBKVQ64218)

Comment: Thanks, but even after using concat, result is empty

Comment: @DKR - Updated just now. Please try now

Comment: Using where, returns all the rows :(

Comment: Too many tables? do you mean rows? I am using the same tables as you (well one less which is not related to the problem).

Comment: No I mean tables. I am already using 3 tables in this query, adding one more wouldn't slow the query? Wouldn't it cause performance issue. Otherwise your solution is coorect.

Comment: @DKR - I didnt add one more table.. I changed the design for `places_main` table .

Comment: Okay. The thing is, Places_main might contain more columns in future and  for that I might need another tables to keep track of tags. Thats where no of tables will increased in query. Would this slow the query?

Comment: @DKR - Not as much slow as the ugly join operation based on concat.. Even so, you can speed up the things easily using proper indexes.

Comment: Okay. Thaks for your help and valuable time :)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the quotes from round the like value

```
select * from places_main pm 
LEFT JOIN travel_list tl ON pm.ID = tl.PLACEID 
LEFT JOIN user_interests ui ON pm.TAGS NOT LIKE '"%' || ui.interestid || '%"'
where tl.ID is null and ui.ID is null
```

Comment: I made that change.. still not effect

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your mysql does not allow the pipe for concat. The || works in MySQL as well but you need to set sql_mode to PIPES_AS_CONCAT.

Or you use "concat()":

```
select * from places_main pm 
LEFT JOIN travel_list tl ON pm.ID = tl.PLACEID 
LEFT JOIN user_interests ui ON pm.TAGS NOT LIKE CONCAT('"%|', ui.interestid, '|%"')
where tl.ID is null and ui.ID is null
```

Comment: I have used Concat , still same issue. The thing is, If i remove pipe form table data and compare it as single value, it works fine. But with piple in row it returns empty. Any suggestion for this??

Comment: What happens if you hard-code NOT LIKE '%|18|%' (... with pipes)?

Comment: maybe your pipe in your data is a different character - which just looks like a pipe?